# Obtain the data in bins (group data)?

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I have a sorted list and I want to group the value in it by its max value and min value with a given number of buckets of equal width, e.g

```
list = [-1.8, -1.7, -1.3, 0.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2]
```

after grouping (with 5 buckets)

```
[[-1.8, -1.7, -1.3], [], [0.6], [2.7], [3.1, 3.2]]
```

(result in list is not necessary, it can be any convenient data structure). After some search I find a solution, by using `bisect`:

```
import bisect

min = list[0]
max = list[-1]
seperator = [x for x in np.linespace(min, max, 6)]
grouped = [[] for _ in range(5)]
for x in list[:-1]:
    idx = bisect.bisect_right(seperator, x)
    grouped[idx-1].append(x)
grouped[-1].append(max)
```

Later I found there are some more straight way to ***almost*** achieve this goal, like, `numpy.histogram`:

```
hist, bins = numpy.histogram(list, bins=5)
```

or `pandas.cut`, but still there is a small gap to the result I want, i.e, to get the data in each bins, and all I find close to that is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275924/how-to-get-data-in-a-histogram-bin), which I think is essentially same as `bisect`.

So, is there a clear way to fill this gap?

Comment: If your min/max is separate by 5, shouldn't you expect each bin to be separated by 1, hence having your final bin containing anything from 2.2 to 3.2 - which is what numpy and/or pandas is going to do.

Comment: Do you really have to use `numpy` or just pure `Python`?